# Why am I getting formula parse error from my custom function?

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I am using a custom function to format urls in google sheets:

```
   /*
   * Formats the page urls
   */


    function URLS(page_url_list){
      const urls = [];
    
      for(let i = 0; i < page_url_list.pages.length; i++){
        urls.push(page_url_list.pages[i].page_url + "\n");
      }
    
      return urls;
    }
```

When I try to use it in google sheets

```
    =URLS({
       "pages" : [
         { 
           "id" : 0,
           "page_url" : "..."
         }
       ]
    })
```

I am getting a formula parse error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object is not supported by formula, you may need to change it into a JSON string and then do `JSON.parse` in your function.

```
=URLS("{
       ""pages"" : [
         { 
           ""id"" : 0,
           ""page_url"" : ""...""
         }
       ]
    }")
```

or

```
=URLS("{
       'pages' : [
         { 
           'id' : 0,
           'page_url' : '...'
         }
       ]
    }")
```

and replace `'` with `"` in you function before doing `JSON.parse`.